# Is there a complete index of D&D 3.5 material?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

D&D 4th edition has the Compendium, a complete searchable index of all official WotC content.

Is there something similar for D&D 3.5 material?

Comment: Assume you mean more than simply http://www.d20srd.org/ (which is only the Open Game Licensed content)? I think not . . . But it might be worth clarifying what you are looking for in more detail.

Comment: Ah, you mean a searchable index of the contents of all material, not just a searchable index of all 3.5 materials themselves. My bad for not reading more carefully! I've deleted my answer.

Answer (score 7):

No. It's unfortunate too, as 3.5 has a lot of material. Unfortunately it came out before WOTC really adopted the Internet and so they never consolidated everything.

The closest things I know of are:

1. [d20 SRD website](http://www.d20srd.org/), which is complete for SRD available material, including errata updates (and has nothing that isn't SRD material).
2. [D&D Tools](http://dndtools.eu/), which is a not-complete but still quite in-depth searchable source for spells, feats, classes, and the like. (Note that copyright issues make this site illegal in a lot of jurisdictions, and has a disclaimer about not using it if you don't own the book in question.)
3. [IMarvinTPA's database](http://www.imarvintpa.com/dndlive/index.php), which is also searchable and has a lot of stuff.

[D&D Wiki](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Main_Page) also has some stuff, but it has homebrew mixed in with officially released content, so be careful when using that for official material.